# How can we call a .vsq file in canalyzer?

Tags: capl, canalyzer

I'm working on **CANalyzer** and I want to call a file (**.vsq**) in it using **CAPL**. How can we do this?

Comment: What does a .vsq file contain? What do you mean by "I want to call"? Does it have any functions which you want to call? Please give more details about what you have tried until now.

Comment: @Shyam In CANalyzer .vsq file corresponds to a visual sequencer file which consists of few steps like sending of frames, checking value of any system variable, etc. Here, "I want to call" means, I want to use/read this file and perform the steps mentioned in the file through CAPL scripting. I have created one .vsq file but I'm not getting any command to read this file in CAPL script.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that it is not possible to start/stop a visual sequence directly via CAPL. Only way to automate (control start/stop) a Visual Sequencer is via COM interface.

**WORKAROUND** 
 *TO START* 
To start a sequence via CAPL, add a "Wait For" command at the start of the sequence, assign a system variable to it and enable "Start sequence on measurement start". In CAPL, change the system variable as per the condition which you had set to start the visual sequence.
*CHECK IF STOPPED*
There is no way to stop a visual sequence via CAPL. But you can check if the sequence is running or not by adding a "Set" command at the end of the sequence and keep monitoring if that system variable has changed or not.